# I don’t understand this instance of “importer”

Tags: vocabulaire

I found this sentence and I’ve tried to translate it but I can’t seem to find out what exactly it means.

www.wordreference.com said the verb “importer” was to import or for something to be important but I can’t see what sense that makes in this sentence:

> “Je ferais bien d’importer la méthode chez nous”

I would do well to make the method important at our house??

Answer (score 6):

It's really "to import" (as opposed to export).

> Je ferais bien d’importer la méthode chez nous.

Without more context given, I'd explain it like this:

> We saw a different method. *(context implicit)*
>  We find it interesting. *(that's implicit)*
>  We might
>   apply it ourself *(in our home/company, country, it depends what "chez
>   nous" refers to, but without context, it's hard to guess)*. Clearly, I
>   should do so. *(for "je ferais bien")*

So instead of importing/exporting products (like we use to for fruits, etc.), we import an abstract thing, in your case a method.